# Can't seem to write to input stream of Powershell from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell, inputstream

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()


        Dim Info As New ProcessStartInfo
        Info.FileName = "powershell"
        Info.Arguments = ""
        Info.RedirectStandardInput = True
        Info.UseShellExecute = False
        Dim P As New Process
        P = Process.Start(Info)
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = P.StandardInput
        Dim Written As Boolean = False
        Do Until Written = True
            Do
                sw.WriteLine("echo pen")
                sw.WriteLine("pause")
            Loop
            'Written = True
        Loop
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I run this code with cmd in place of powershell, it works as expected - however, if I try to run Powershell with this code, Powershell just blinks at me, ignoring the fact that I am sending input - does anyone know why? and how to fix it?

(The code has been made to loop forever for demonstration purposes.)

Comment: `Info.Arguments = "-Command -"`

Comment: I need to run more than one command at a time - the first command is going to run a .ps1 script to set up a bunch of environment variables, the the other is going run a script to set up build dependencies, and a third to actually run a build application.

Comment: I tried it your way, but this errors out trying to add 7z to path:

`Info.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command ""$env:path = $env:path + " & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\7z""; setenv.ps1; install; publish -Server ""OpenRCT2.net & Punfumblercraft.com"" -BuildNumber """ & BuildNumber & """ -GitBranch ""Develop"""`

Comment: No what @PetSerAl is trying to say is that the argument to `-Command` is literally a dash (`-`) if you want powershell to pick out commands from STDIN

Comment: ...Oh. Well then, I am going to go ahead and re-try that then.